# Datesets - users accessing database tables

Tags: data-request

I'm trying to model user behavior on database tables. Do you know any public date sets of the form: *User U accesses table T*.

I.e. I need a data set of the sort [user u,table t,timestamp], that states that table t appeared in a query executed by by user u.

Also, a data set of the form *user accesses/uses/... Object* would suffice.

Comment: Can you tell a little more ([edit] your question)? *behavior on database tables* says very little. The way these are accessed will depend on the purpose, thus the structure, of the entire databases. It is not as if any group of users of any database has the same behaviour...

Comment: Basically i need a date set of the sort [user u,table t,timestamp], that states that table t appeared in a query by user u.

Comment: Yes, but *why*? This does not look as if this is going to give you meaningful information, since database use completely depends on the reason it was constructed in the first place. If anybody has a log for user/program X using database B, this is not going to tell you anything about 'your case' of Y accessing C.

Comment: Turn on audit functionality in your database, this will give you that sort of statistics.